# indexOf is not working during search the object in array in ionic3?

Tags: ionic3

i have to get the index Of selected Object but i got every time return -1 tell me whats the wrong in my code here i will updated the html and ts code ?

```js
addOrRemoveSubcategory(event:any, subCategroyObject: any) {
    //For firestore - Here we will hold the subcateoryObject and push into array 
    this.checkedCategoryObject = {
      "id"                 : subCategroyObject.keyId,
      "subCategoryName"    : subCategroyObject.subCategoryName
    }

    if(event.checked) {
      this.selectedSubCategoryKeyId = subCategroyObject.keyId;
      //Push only if not eixst in the array
      if(this.selectedSubCategoryArray.indexOf(this.checkedCategoryObject.id) == -1){
        this.selectedSubCategoryArray.push(this.checkedCategoryObject);
      }
    } else {
      this.selectedSubCategoryKeyId = subCategroyObject.keyId;
      var index         = this.selectedSubCategoryArray.indexOf(this.checkedCategoryObject);
      this.selectedSubCategoryArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

```html
<ion-item-sliding>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let subCategoryObj of adminSubCategrotDto">
    <ion-checkbox dark (ionChange)="addOrRemoveSubcategory($event, subCategoryObj)"
       item-left>
    </ion-checkbox>
    <ion-label>{{subCategoryObj.subCategoryName}}</ion-label>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img src="{{subCategoryObj.defaultImageURL}}">
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-item>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

[image]

Comment: Add your HTML code how you are adding or removing object through HTML ?

Comment: sir check my updated fiddle and tell m what i am wrong here?